# We want stackoverflooooooow stickers

Tags: feature-request, 10m-questions-milestone

There's a new logo on Stack Overflow:

[image: ooooooo]

Will you be making "stackoverflooooooow" stickers?

I'm not huge fan of stickers as they are a one-shot thing so I'm always sooooooo hesitant of which ones to actually stick, but....

I want this one (or couple...)!  Please fix the bug of missing stickers!

Comment: This seems to be asking if we'll be making any stuff with the celebratory logo, not _just_ asking if there's merchandise available in general, you insensitive clods :P

Comment: @TimPost, although it does answer my question ... by breaking my celebration heart :/ :P

Comment: There *are* services which provide custom shirts / stickers and so forth. Just be quiet about using the SO logo and don't attempt to profit from it.

Comment: @Trobbins Yep, that's why I thought the reason in the "Is there any plans" does not apply completely.

Comment: (sees edits) <strike>cool but why the downvotes</strike> I *knew* asking this will be fun! :D

Comment: @AloisMahdal I well know, that's why I use that nick ;-) ...

Comment: Why isn't the question *We want stackoverflo,ooo,ooow stickers*? :D

Comment: "sooooooo hesitant" 7 o's. I'm onto you.

Comment: @BhargavRao Frankly I don't really like (or see, unless I squint really hard) the commas.

Comment: I get it that repeating the 'o's permit the commas, but they grate on my eyes (even more than the "network" background) - it should be the 'w' that's repeated.  Ommv, of course.

Comment: How about condoms? Not only do they promote safe sex, but you get to see if you can achieve the full set of O's.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Stickers? *possibly*. It would be a cool way for people to 'own' a small part of the event beyond the stuff that they contributed to make it happen. The cool thing about our stickers is that they're re-usable, you can peel them off of your laptop and then stick them to your hair if you want, or some other gadget you want to adorn.

We're looking into it :) No promises yet, but it's not a horrible idea.

Comment: Thanks for un-breaking my heart!

Comment: Not as horrible of an idea as sticking stickers to your own hair, at least.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Speak for yourself, I find it very therapeutic. It's pulling them off later that can get ugly.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect stickers for kids that can't make up their mind where the stickers should go. Should it go on my shirt? Or my pants? Or the cat? Maybe the wall (but only if I really really push it into the wall, we don't want it to fall off)? Nah...I'll put it on my shirt again. *crying starts because the sticker no longer sticks*

Comment: How well do they stick to other surfaces after they've been on, say, a cat for a few days?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'll let you know once all of my cuts have healed.

Comment: Wait, there's stickers for *your hair*? I have been missing out!

Comment: (Monty Python mode on) ... no, not **that** gadget again. (Monty Python mode off)

Comment: Guaranteed stickers for users with rep 75k+

Comment: ^LMFAO says the person with 75,665 rep

Comment: @TimPost as a matter of fact I am very proud I had a minor impact on SO (I am a tiny user). I would be proud to show that in any way and stickers would be super nice. I wish I could buy them from country, without having to mail SO.